# what is the best way to integrate salesforce with microsoft ax?

Tags: api, integration

what is the best way to integrate salesforce with Microsoft AX?

I can see some apps available in the appexchange, is that a good choice?
or should i use a Microsoft AX API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is better to use some tools from app-exchange since they would have tested it out well so that you it would be robust & less down time.